# Excel VBA Find all Key values, Make a comma separated Unique List of Values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub POs()
    Const csQuery As String = "Query"
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim rRows As Dictionary
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim sFirstMatch As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

input_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
data_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet6.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet6.Name).Columns("A")
Set rInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).Range("A2:A" & input_lRow)
Set rOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name)
Set rRows = New Dictionary

For Each c In rInput
    sName = c
    Set rFind = rData.Find(sName)
    If rFind Is Nothing Then
        rOutput.Range("J" & c.Row).Value = "No PO Found"
    Else
        sFirstMatch = rFind.Address
        Do
            Set rFind = rData.FindNext(rFind)
            rRows.Add Key:=sName, Item:=rFind.Offset(, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
        Loop While rFind.Address <> sFirstMatch
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far; it creates the dictionary.  The part I am having a hard time with is If the KEY in the dictionary matches the value of the cell in rOutput Column A, then put all the ITEM values in a comma separated list in cell J

Psuedo Code:
If KEY = rOutput.Range("A2") THEN rOutput.Range("J2").Value = JOIN(rRows.Item,", ")

Here is what I tried:

```
Sub POs()
    Const csQuery As String = "Query"
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim rRows As Dictionary
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim sFirstMatch As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

input_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
data_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet6.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet6.Name).Columns("A")
Set rInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).Range("A2:A" & input_lRow)
Set rOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name)
Set rRows = New Dictionary

For Each c In rInput
    sName = c
    Set rFind = rData.Find(sName)
    If rFind Is Nothing Then
        rOutput.Range("J" & c.Row).Value = "No PO Found"
    Else
        sFirstMatch = rFind.Address
        Do
            Set rFind = rData.FindNext(rFind)
            rRows.Add Key:=sName, Item:=rFind.Offset(, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
        Loop While rFind.Address <> sFirstMatch
    End If
    For Each Key In rRows.Keys
        If Key = sName Then
            rOutput.Range("J" & c.Row).Value = Join(rRows.Items, ", ")
        End If
    Next Key
Next c
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it is not restarting the dictionary for each row.  When I tried to Set rRows = New Dictionary before the Next c, I only ever get a single PO again.

How can I fix this to give me all unique POs for each of the rows in the input sheet?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do in more detail. Especially the part where you are using the `Find` method and what you are writing to the dictionary. Maybe if you could post some sample data.

Comment: You cannot add the same key twice, you will get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

2 things:

1. I needed to swap what was a key and what was an item.  I had them
   backwards.
2. I had to move my loop around for the output into the Do
   While and reset the dictionary outside of that loop.

   ```
   input_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RnO Input Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   data_lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("POs").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("POs").Columns("A")
   Set rInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RnO Input Data").Range("A2:A" & input_lRow)
   Set rOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name)
   Set rRows = New Dictionary

   For Each c In rInput
       Set rFind = rData.Find(c)
       If rFind Is Nothing Then
           rOutput.Range("J" & c.Row).Value = "No PO Found"
       Else
           sFirstMatch = rFind.Address
           Do
               rRows.Add Key:=rFind.Offset(, 2), Item:=c
               Set rFind = rData.FindNext(rFind)
               'On Error Resume Next
               For Each k In rRows.Keys
                   If rRows.Item(k) = c Then
                       rOutput.Range("J" & c.Row).Value = Join(rRows.Keys, ", ")
                   End If
               Next k
           Loop While rFind.Address <> sFirstMatch
           Set rRows = New Dictionary
       End If
   Next c
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution below:

- Uses one dictionary for the entire process instead of one per row.
- Uses the dictionary to hold the values of the cells found, instead of the ranges.
- Updates the output only once after the `For…Next` loop has been completed.

  ```
    Sub POs_MATCH()
    Dim oDtn As Dictionary
    Dim rPOs As Range, rOutput As Range
    Dim aInput As Variant, vOP As Variant
    Dim rFind As Range, s1stFnd As String
    Dim sOutput As String, lRow As Long
    Dim exCalc As XlCalculation

        Rem Excel Properties OFF
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            exCalc = .Calculation
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .CalculateBeforeSave = False
        End With

        Set oDtn = New Dictionary
        With ThisWorkbook

            With .Worksheets("RnO Input Data")
                lRow = -1 + .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                aInput = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(lRow).Value
                Set rOutput = .Cells(2, 10).Resize(lRow)
            End With

            With .Worksheets("POs")
                lRow = -1 + .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rPOs = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(lRow)

        End With: End With

        For Each vOP In aInput

            sOutput = vbNullString
            Set rFind = rPOs.Find(vOP)

            If rFind Is Nothing Then
                oDtn.Add 1 + oDtn.Count, "No PO Found"

            Else

                s1stFnd = rFind.Address
                Do
                    sOutput = sOutput & ", " & rFind.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Set rFind = rPOs.FindNext(rFind)
                Loop Until rFind.Address = s1stFnd

                oDtn.Add 1 + oDtn.Count, Mid(sOutput, 3)

        End If: Next

        rOutput.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(oDtn.Items)

        Rem Excel Properties OFF
        With Application
            .Calculation = exCalc
            .CalculateBeforeSave = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With

        End Sub
  ```